# Recursive function has a void data type but error shows up

Tags: java, recursion

This is for school work. We have to write a program for decimal to octal conversion. The recursive function for octal conversion is given as void deci_oct(int x). when I try to call the function inside it and send the value n/8, the error "void type not allowed here" shows up. The question requires that the return type of the recursive function should be void. Any help is appreciated.

```
void deci_oct()
    {
        if(n > 0){
            int r=n%8;
            n/=8;
            deci_oct();
            oct =(oct * 10)+r;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You are attempting to add an integer to a void, which is non-sensical. Perhaps you're trying to create a string?

Comment: You could put the logic with the recursion into a helper function and then call it from your `deci_oct` function. That way your helper function can use non-void return types.

Comment: You can always introduce a helper method `int deci_oct_helper(int x)` which does all the work and just call that one. Note that if the function does not return anything and there is no state to mutate then the method is pretty pointless. But it seems that `sum` is actual state, which is equally bad, particularly because you do not initialize it with anything, calling `deci_oct` repeatedly will produce unexpected results.

Comment: @Dave Newton   That is what I do not understand, the question deals with integer data types, there is no mention of string data type anywhere, but the recursive function has been listed as a void data type.

Comment: What sense would it make to convert an integer *n* to an octal *n*? Still just an integer. A "conversion" only makes sense if you're talking about a *representation* of an integer--an integer doesn't care what base its in, it's only when *representations* are converted to an integer that it matters. E.g., `int x = 010` vs `int x = 10` where the source code string representation matters. `x` is the same regardless.

Comment: You have defined the method this way `void deci_oct(int x)` it returns void. So you can't us it in expression.

Comment: I unfortunately do not know anything about helper method. I will search it up and update you accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: `... + deci_oct(n/8)` - what did you expect from this? `deci_oct` returns `void`(nothing)

Comment: @DaveNewton Would it help if I linked the question?

Comment: Also in your `while(n>7)`, you never update the value of `n`, which will produce infinite loop.

Comment: @electric_bugaloo Not really; it'd be better if the problem statement was in your post. My point is that converting an integer to "an octal" only makes sense if the output is a *string*.

Comment: @KunLun n/8 would pass the quotient in the function from which the remainder would be taken out and assigned to their place value by multiplying the remainder with 10 to the power of the increment value.

Comment: @electric_bugaloo KunLun's point was that you never modify `n`, so the `while` loop would never terminate. If the goal is to make a *single* decision based on the value of `n` then an `if` statement would be better. But it's unclear what `n` even is.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes, I understand now. I changed the while loop to n>0. And i figured it out. I first made a small program that converts decimal to octal numbers without recursion in integer data type and tried out the logic in the void function and surprisingly it works. I will edit my code to the new functioning one. I actually was making a mistake in passing an argument, namely int x in the void function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in a short way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    System.out.println(octal(210)); // 322
    octal(210, builder);
    System.out.println(builder.toString()); // 322
    octalVoid(210);// 322
}
```

**Example 1:** Return type void with the builder.

```
static void octal(int value, StringBuilder builder) {
    if (value < 0) {
        octal(-value, builder);
    }
    if (value < 8) {
        builder.append(value);
    } else {
        octal(value / 8, builder);
        builder.append(value % 8);
    }
}
```

**Example 2:** Return type string.

```
static String octal(int value) {
    if (value < 0) {
        return "-" + octal(-value);
    }
    return value < 8 ? String.valueOf(value) : octal(value / 8) + value % 8;
}
```

**Example 3:** Return type void with print.

```
static void octalVoid(int value) {
    if (value < 0) {
        octal(-value);
    }
    if (value < 8) {
        System.out.print(value);
    } else {
        octalVoid(value / 8);
        System.out.print(value % 8);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, however it unfortunately does not comply with the assigned question from our teacher. The recursive function needs to be a return type void. if it had not been, i would've definitely used your solution. Thank you for your effort and time!

Comment: I provided multiple examples.

Comment: I apologize, I'm a little new to using stack overflow, and i did not expand your comment. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could print the result digit by digit using `Sytem.out.print()` and `...flush()` instead of trying to first construct the full number before printing it (originally, the code in the question was using System.out.println() to print the converted number, presumably avoiding a return value, as per the task).

Probably the "tricky" bit is supposed to be that you need to first calculate the digit, then call the recursion for the rest, then print in order to get the digit order right....

```
void deci_oct(int n) {
    if (n > 8) {
      deci_oct(n / 8);
    }
    System.out.print(n % 8);
    System.out.flush(); // might not be needed
}
```

p.s. Typically one would convert the value to a string and hand in a StringBuilder for this purpose, avoiding excessive string copying

Comment: I donot know about the flush() method, but thank you for suggesting, i will look it up and try to incorporate it in my programs further on.

Comment: It might not be needed here -- it just makes sure the print output is "flushed" to the screen (opposed to being buffered internally). println() does this implicitly. BTW: Try to avoid editing your question in ways that the answers no longer match, confusing readers; consider appending new content instead

Comment: Ah! I apologize. I am absolutely new here, thank you for the advise.

Comment: No worries. If an answer actually answers your question, consider accepting it, "closing" this question